# What's the difference between [UIApplication sharedApplication] and application argument of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm now learning about background fetch functionality in iOS 7 and Xcode 5, and I've read a few tutorials explaining how to set `setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval` within `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

One type of sample code I've read is the following one:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval: UIApplicationBackgroundFetchMinimum];
    return YES;
}
```

And the other is the following, which utilizes the `application` argument to set its background initialization:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval: UIApplicationBackgroundFetchMinimum];
    return YES;
```

However, I don't get what makes one different from the other in the two codes above. The `shareApplication` class method returns `UIApplication *`, which is exactly the same as the type of the `application` argument.

And if there are NOT any differences between the two, what's the point of using the former? As far as I read, there are more samples taking the first approach, but I always feel the simpler is better (again, if there is NO difference - I think some differences exists, as mentioned above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no diferences, using the method parameter is useful when you don't know which class sent that message (for example, imagine that you have several `UITableView`, all of them with the same delegate, you want to know which one called the delegate).

In this case, there's only one `UIAplication` per App, and that's the one that is in your `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` and the one that calls the delegate.

Summarising, is just the same object and there's no diference, just style.

Extending the example, imagine that you have a variable like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *myTable;
```

Yo do:

```
self.myTable.delegate = self;
```

When the delegate is called, theres are equivalents:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//self.myTable = tableView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't it mean the former takes one more redundant method call, right (though the cost is decidedly negligible)?

Comment: It does take one more call, but I dont think is even noticeable. It's just a matter of style.

Comment: It might not be noticeable, but there is no need to waste [nanoseconds](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEpsKnWZrJ8).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, there is no difference.

It's probably a matter of style/preference as to which option you use.

I use [UIApplication sharedApplication].

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference UIApplication is a singleton class and [UIApplication sharedApplication] is a way to access that shared variable of singleton class If you are calling the method from UIApplication class itself then using application is enough to access the method.